# "Dissipation increases with higher viscosity" versus "Dissipation increases with the viscosity"

Tags: word-choice

I feel like the second option is better because less redundant, but I do find examples in scientific papers of the use of both. Are they both correct? If that is the case, is one recommended?

Comment: There's no law that says "increases with viscosity" means "increases with increasing viscosity" rather than "increases with decreasing viscosity."

Comment: If you have an equation with coefficients, that's much better than a verbal description. Is the increase linear, for instance?

Comment: That was just an example. XXX increases with higher XXX. it is used on google scholar papers if you search for "increases with higher ". Isn't it redundant? Isn't it enough to say XXX increases with  XXX? In Italian we use the second option not the first.

Comment: As John Lawler mentioned, not including *increasing* strongly suggests a linear dependence of dissipation on viscosity. By adding *increasing*, you remove that stricture and leave the nature of the dependence open. In Newtonian Fluids, dissipation is linear wrt viscosity. If you have stated the relation is linear, you're good to go with the second one.

Comment: I never spoke about removing or adding the word "increasing". I am asking if "higher" is needed or not. Not me it is redundant. Can adding "higher"  be considered wrong in English? In my language it is. This has nothing to do with linearity or not. Something can increase or decrease linearly, quadratically, or exponentially, my question is still valid.

Comment: And I am not sure I agree with Hot Licks. In scientific publication "A increases with B" implicitly means "A increases with increasing B". No one ever would understand "A increases with decreasing B". Do we agree with this? Even if I never stated the relationship before?

Comment: I agree with you. Unless you specify the nature of the relationship, the default assumption is that they change in the same direction. Whether it's linear, quadratic, exponential is ambiguous, though.

Comment: But there can also be cases where common sense applies. If you say "The odds of winning the lottery decrease with participation", it's obvious that odds decrease as participation incrases.

Comment: I agree. And it always means that. There is no way that "X decreases with Y" means anything else then "if Y increases X decreases"

Answer (score -1):

**( A )** There are Contexts where "Dissipation increases with **higher** viscosity" is redundant , hence "Dissipation increases with the viscosity" is better.

**( B )** There are Contexts where "Dissipation increases with **higher** viscosity" is not redundant hence it is more accurate than "Dissipation increases with the viscosity" , which may even be wrong.

**[ Example A ]** Liquid X has the Property that when Viscosity V goes from 0% to 100% , Dissipation D too goes from 0% to 100% : here **Higher is entirely redundant**.

**[ Example B ]** Liquid Y has the Property that (i) when V goes from 0% to 10% , D goes from 30% to 15% , (ii) with V between 10% & 40% , D is almost constant at 15% (iii) when V goes from 40% to 100% , D goes from 15% to 100% : here we may claim that "Dissipation increases with higher viscosity" : here **Higher is not redundant**. It is wrong to claim "Dissipation increases with the viscosity". We are contrasting with lower viscosity , where it was Decreasing , then staying Constant.

**Summary :**
When either way is "correct" then avoid "higher" , which is redundant.
When one way is "correct" & other way is "wrong" , then use the "correct" way.
**Context matters !**

Comment: One would say 'dissipation increases with viscosity over the range v₂ - v₃, but not ...'.

Comment: Yes , we might say "Liquid Z has the property that , though D is negligible in middle V range , D increases with higher V" , where the Sentence might be "??wrong??" without higher , @EdwinAshworth

Comment: I dont agree @Prem, in your example both "Dissipation increases with higher viscosity" and "Dissipation increases with viscosity" are wrong. To me those 2 expressions are ALWAYS fully equivalent. If you think they are not, please provide an example in which only one is right and the other is wrong, not when they are both wrong.

Comment: I have already given the "liquid X" Example where those 2 expressions are ALWAYS fully equivalent , @Millemila , while the "liquid Y" Example requires "higher" when talking about the higher range.

Comment: I am sorry but that is not the case. You need to re-read what you wrote. No one upvoting you clearly shows that that is not a correct answer. In that example higher is not needed. You can just state propertoe for each interval: e.g. one thing increases with another for that interval, and for the other interval that thing decreases with another. Higher is not needed, nor it helps at all

Comment: (A) Down-vote/up-vote does not indicate correctness. Your Question has not been upvoted : It does not mean Q is not valid. My Answer might be wrong , but till now , it has not been shown to be wrong (B) You said that you have seen both usages in Papers : (B1) Why do you think those Papers are wrong ? (B2) Why not include those Example Papers in your Post , which will let us check ? (C) In my Answer , I have a Summary Section : Do you agree with that assessment ? @Millemila